# MPI with Qt 5.0.2 on OSX (Lion)

Tags: qt, osx-lion, mpi

I have tried to install openmpi (first through macports, which did not work to include), then separately from source directly version 1.4.3 (64-bit) to /usr/local/.

My config in Qt (.pro) looks as following:

```
CONFIG += x86_64
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -lmpi
```

I get one warning: :-1: Warnung:directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Qt/5.0.2/clang_64/qtbase/lib'

And one error: :-1: Fehler:symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64.

Details show: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any ideas?

I have also tried MPICH2 which does not work either.

Comment: have you also changed the compiler to the mpic++ and mpicc?

Comment: Hm, how would I do that? I apparently only have gcc or clang, would I need to create a custom entry in the Compiler settings section with mpic++/mpicc?

Comment: Then you should install a mpuc++ compiler.